# Convert MYSQL datetime coulmn into JSON - SPRING BOOT

Tags: mysql, sql, json, spring

I have been working in converting the MYSQL table values to JSON .  My table has following column
`entry_time timestamp`. The following is working well for the conversion of data but while converting the data to JSON i have following value after conversion into JSON

```
    public String convertTableDatatoJSON(String tableNAME) throws SQLException {
        String tableName = tableNAME;
        Connection connection = createConnection();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        List<String> columns = loadColumns(connection, tableName);
        ResultSet dataSet = loadData(connection, tableName);
        while (dataSet.next()) {
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
            for (String column : columns) {
                record.put(column, dataSet.getObject(column));
            }
            array.add(record);
        }
        jsonObject.put(tableName, array);
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("src/main/resources/JSONdata/" + tableName + ".json");
            file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Data from table " + tableNAME + " is converted to JSON successfully. ";
    }
```

> Actual Result : "entry_time" : 0000-00-00 00:00:00
>
> Expected Result : "entry_time" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

I just wanted to **put the inverted commas** while converting the table data to of column having *timestamp* datatype to JSON.

Comment: have you tried doing so? `` record.put(column, dataSet.getObject(column)).toString();``

Comment: @OMiShah this is not working in my case  either . By trying your suggestion it through the error java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: While saving data in list, add( "\" "+data+" \"")

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram sorry, there was an error try ``record.put(column, dataSet.getObject(column).toString());``

Comment: @OMiShah I have also tried this .But didn't work. Please have a look to the accepted answer of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the built-in method but you should try it manually by concatenating the string with it.

```
record.put(column, ""+dataSet.getObject(column)+"");
```

update this line as this.
It will make you `column` object as `String` and `String` is always in the double quotation which is exactly as per your requirements.